# Which is the best torrent client for Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: utorrent, torrent-client

I searched utorrent site, but it is given for lower versions of ubuntu. Which one do you suggest ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Ubuntu comes with Transmission.
You can also use deluge which a lot of people like.
To get Deluge just use:

```
sudo apt-get install deluge
```

http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Installing/Linux/Ubuntu

I also recommend using a VPN to keep your IP safe/hidden. Very big deal these days.

Private Internet Access is my favorite, it costs a few bucks a month but it is secure and they don't keep logs which is kinda a big deal too.

https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/buy-vpn/

Comment: How to use a free VPN?

Comment: Early indications for me suggest deluge is better than transmission (and transmission isn't on my Ubuntu 14.04 unless I install it I think).